# Decoding aac to PCM in ffmpeg introduces noise in the raw PCM audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, aac, decoding, pcm

I have a .mp4 file generated with ffmpeg as follows.

> ffmpeg -y -i video_extended.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:04.00 -i output5-1.wav -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ac 6 -ar 48000 -b:a 128k -async 1 mixed.mp4

Playing `mixed.mp4` file with ffplay is fine and there is no impact to the sound quality. Below is the output I get from ffplay when using the command `ffplay -i  mixed.mp4`

```
> Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from
> 'mixed_h264_aac_512k_async_qp0_all_I.mp4':   Metadata:
>     major_brand     : isom
>     minor_version   : 512
>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>     encoder         : Lavf58.76.100   Duration: 00:00:16.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49136 kb/s   Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv422p10le(progressive),
> 1920x1080, 65409 kb/s, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 11988 tbn (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]   Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 71 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>       vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0] Switch subtitle stream from #-1 to #-1 vq= 1606KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

Then, I decode the `mixed.mp4` file back to raw PCM using the following command.

> ffmpeg -i mixed.mp4 -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -f s16le -ar 48000 -ac 6 raw_audio.pcm

However, this `raw_audio.pcm` contains a lot of noise and ffplay output shows the following output

```
[s16le @ 0x7f7490000c80] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, s16le, from 'separated_audio_s16.pcm':
  Duration: 00:00:16.02, bitrate: 4607 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 6 channels, s16, 4608 kb/s
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Multiple frames in a packet.
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 32 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
Switch subtitle stream from #-1 to #-1 vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
    Last message repeated 11 times
[pcm_s16le @ 0x7f749002b940] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 8 but at least a size of 12 was expected
```

Can someone please explain the issue here? Note that the ffplay command that works correctly for `mixed.mp4` shows  `fltp` as the audio format, whereas when playing the `raw_audio.pcm` file, it is seen as s16.

Also, I have tried the same process with files containing stereo audio and it works fine. You can reproduce the problem by downloading the .mp4 file in [here](https://www2.iis.fraunhofer.de/AAC/ChID-BLITS-EBU.mp4).

Is this a resampling issue in ffmpeg when processing multi-channel audio, and how can I rectify this?

I’m using ffmpeg and ffplay versions 5.0.1 in a Fedora 36 system.

Thank you.